# Data Transfer from MySql to SQL server using SSMS

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to load data's from MySQL tables to SQL server 2012 tables.
For that  i installed "mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.4-win32" driver.

After that importing data using data source " .Net Framework Data Provider For Odbc"

I gave correct connection-string and DSN for Mysql .

At last am getting an error

```
    - Setting Source Connection (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc02020ff: Source - r_cluster [1]: The Source - r_cluster was unable to retrieve column information for the SQL command. The following error occurred: ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.25]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"r_cluster"' at line 1
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Pipeline component has returned HRESULT error code 0xC02020FF from a method call. (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I have just looked for the solution to this problem for myself and found the following to work.
In your ODBC Settings (make sure you are using the ANSI driver

1. Select the details button
2. In Initial statement at the bottom of the
   screen `set session sql_mode=ansi_quotes;`

[MSDN Social - MS server connect to MySQL (ODBC)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3d882dd2-97b6-4d5a-b15b-fc7ff9ef6e8d/ms-server-connect-to-mysql-odbc?forum=sqlintegrationservices)